# Rezound in a boot loop

Tags: reboot, boot-loop, htc-rezound

My Rezound has randomly just turned off and on for a while and it doesn't stop until I take the battery out and remove the SIM card.  Any ways to fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a hard reset, remove sim, set network type to WCDMA preferred.